# Seaborn's boxplot whiskers meaning

Tags: python, seaborn

I'm working with `seaborn`'s box plot, and I can't seem to figure out the placement of the whiskers in the default settings.

Looking at the [`seaborn.boxplot` docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html#seaborn.boxplot) I see that `whis=1.5` which I assumed means that the whiskers are placed at `UPPER_QUARTILE + IQR*1.5` and at `LOWER_QUARTILE - IQR*1.5`.

But even in the docs themselves, looking at the whiskers, we can see that they have different gap lengths from the upper/lower quartiles

[image: docs]

It is easy to see that the lengths on both sides of the box to the whiskers are not equal, so my assumption is obviously wrong.

So how the default whiskers are placed? Or maybe I fail to understand something more basic about the nature of the box plot?

Comment: Why does the distance matter, isn't it based on the distribution? There are obviously a lot of high outliers which will likely move the high quartile further away from the mean.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

IIRC, the whiskers extend to the the lowest (highest) data point still within 1.5 IQR of the lower (upper) quartile.  So depending on where the data points actually are, the whiskers on both sides won't necessarily be of the same length.

Matplotlib [docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.boxplot.html) for the `whis` argument of `boxplot()` (which Seaborn is built on top of) seem to confirm this:

> whis : float, sequence, or string (default = 1.5)
>   As a float, determines the reach of the whiskers to the beyond the first and third quartiles. In other words, where IQR is the interquartile range (Q3-Q1), the upper whisker will extend to last datum less than Q3 + whis*IQR). Similarly, the lower whisker will extend to the first datum greater than Q1 - whis*IQR. Beyond the whiskers, data are considered outliers and are plotted as individual points.

Answer (score 1):

Although the lower and upper ranges expand to the same distance (1.5*IQR) from the box, the whiskers only extend up to the farthest data-point present in these admissible ranges.

The boxplot doesn't plot these ranges mainly because its intended to visualize the dataset itself rather than marking allowed spectrum for data values.
I tried to show these upper and lower limits for this dataset and you can see that they are at the same distance from the 1st and 3rd quartiles:

```
q1 = tips["total_bill"].quantile(0.25)
q3 =tips["total_bill"].quantile(0.75)
iqr = q3 - q1
limit_lower = q1 - 1.5*iqr
limit_upper = q3 + 1.5*iqr
ax = sns.boxplot(x=tips["total_bill"])
plt.scatter(limit_lower,0, color='red')
plt.scatter(limit_upper,0, color='red')
plt.show()
```

Now you can see the considered limits marked by these two red points which clearly show the acceptable range for data values not to be labeled as Outliers.
[image]